# What is the type of this literal?

Tags: go

From the `mgo` docs:

```
pipe := collection.Pipe([]bson.M{{"$match": bson.M{"name": "Otavio"}}})
```

Decomposing this statement, I see that the argument passed to `collection.Pipe` is of type `[]bson.M`.  Given that slices are initialized via `[]sometype{ ... }` syntax, I conclude that the aforementioned slice contains exactly one item (so `len == 1`), and that this item is the `{"$match": bson.M{"name": "Otavio"}}` literal.

What is the type of this literal?  Intuitively, I want to say it's a `map[string]interface{}`, but when I tried checking on the go playground, I'm unable to initialize a similar data structure:  https://play.golang.org/p/7QKYaQPi6g

My question is therefore twofold:

1. What is the type of `https://play.golang.org/p/7QKYaQPi6g` (assuming I've made no mistake in my reasoning)
2. What am I doing wrong in `x := {"foo": 1, "bar": 1}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bson.M` is just another name for `map[string]interface{}`. See its [documentation](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#M). Its declared as,

```
type M map[string]interface{}
```

So, yes `{"$match": bson.M{"name": "Otavio"}` is of type `bson.M`

Comment: The one thing I didn't think to check... this is not one of my most brilliant questions ...  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
x := {"foo": 1, "bar": 1}
```

In this statement there is no chance to deduct the type. When you do something like this:

```
[]bson.M{{"$match": bson.M{"name": "Otavio"}}}
```

Compiler know that you are initializing slice of specific type, so there is no need to repeat this type every time (unless it's interface). This initalisation is called [composite literals](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals) and was introduced in [go1.0](https://golang.org/doc/go1#literals)

Comment: Ah, but of course!  On the other hand I'm still stumped vis a vis the type of the literal, as I'm assuming `{"$match": bson.M{"name": "Otavio"}}` isn't of type `bson.M`.

Comment: [`bson.M`](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#M) is just `map[string]interface{}`. So in your case it's mapping string to another `bson.M`